# How to surround all Bracket groups with * in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to get a string replaceAll to work in Java that was originally from a JavaScript code block. I have the following

```
String regexSearch = "((?!([ \\*]))|^)\\[[A-Za-z0-9\\s]*\\](?!\\*)"; //Java Version must escape special characters again
String regexReplacement = "*$&*";

String inputString = "This is a User, [USER 1], and a second user [USER 2]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexSearch);

Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll(regexReplacement));
```

My desired output is

```
This is a User, *[USER 1]*, and a second user *[USER 2]*
```

I keep getting illegal group reference errors.

Requirements are as follows. Any text that is surrounded by square brackets "[" and "]" will be surrounded by "*" while still retaining the brackets. However if within the bracketed text there is a "|" character then this will not apply.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/VAc2vp/1

Comment: Please confine questions to a question. Your edit turns your question into a discussion.

Comment: The `"\\[[A-Za-z0-9\\s]*?]";` is an unreliable regex, it will fail to match, say, `-` inside `[...]`. The `\\[.*?]` pattern may match too much (like `[32[text[]`). Use `"\\[[^\\]\\[]*]"`

Comment: Also, your previous regex is off: `(?!([ \\*]))` is not doing what it is meant to. It was there to disallow a match after space, ``\`` or `*`. But a lookbehind was necessary, not a lookahead. You can use a lookbehind without fear in Java, it has supported them "natively" for a long time. Do you need a direct regex conversion, or you may live with a generic, lenient `\\[.*?]`?

Comment: I can live with a more lenient version. Thank you for the input. I've modified the edit.

Comment: That means, you are using *my solution*, I posted an [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61239231/3832970), please consider accepting since it seems to have worked best for you. I also provided the direct conversion and fix for your original regex. Note you do not need to escape `|` inside a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial `((?!([ \*]))|^)\[[A-Za-z0-9\s]*\](?!\*)` regex attempts (but fails) to match `[...]` strings when not enclosed with `*` chars. In Java, you would write it as

```
(?<!\*)\[[A-Za-z0-9\s]*](?!\*)
String regexSearch = "(?<!\\*)\[[A-Za-z0-9\\s]*](?!\\*)";
```

However, you may use a more lenient expression like

```
String regexSearch = "\\[[^\\]\\[|]*]";
```

Or, if you need to keep the original behavior to fail the matches inside asterisks:

```
String regexSearch = "(?<!\\*)\\[[^\\]\\[|]*](?!\\*)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QyOsb8/2).

It matches:

- `(?<!\*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `*` char immediately to the left of the current location
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\]\[|]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `|`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(?!\*)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `*` char immediately to the right of the current location.

So, it will match from the `[` till the closest `]` without matching other `[` and `|` inside, i.e. it will match *innermost* substrings between square brackets. It will also allow any other special and non-speical chars inside brackets, like hyphens, apostrophes, etc. `[A-Za-z0-9\s]` only allowed ASCII letters, digits and whitespaces.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/iMcOy2):

```
String regexSearch = "\\[[^\\]\\[|]*]";
String regexReplacement = "*$0*";
String inputString = "This is a User, [USER 1], and a second user [USER 2] not [USER | 3]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexSearch);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll(regexReplacement));
// => This is a User, *[USER 1]*, and a second user *[USER 2]* not [USER | 3]
```

Comment: Moving acceptance to this answer as it is the must complete answer for the specified question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about matching the whole line, the following is sufficient:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Replacing this with `*[$1]*`.

[Here's](https://regexr.com/52it2) a demo on RegExr.

Further explanation: taking each element in the regex in turn:

- `\[` - we need to escape the opening square bracket because square brackets are a reserved character in regular expressions.
- `(.*?)` - the `.*?` matches zero or more of any character [lazily](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/why-using-the-greedy-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want#lazy-quantifiers-to-the-rescue).  This is surrounded in parentheses to indicate it's a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
- `]` - close the square bracket.

We then replace this with an an asterisk followed by an open square bracket `*[`, the first capture group `$1` and then the closing square bracket and another asterisk. `]*`.

Comment: So do you mean `*$1*`? The way you currently have it puts the * inside the brackets whereas I need it outside.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

- `String.replaceAll` -- first argument is a regex.
- The second argument is the replacement string. The `$1` is capture group.

```
String regexSearch = "\\[.*?]";     
String inputString = "This is a User, [USER 1], and a second user [USER 2]";
inputString = inputString.replaceAll(regexSearch, "*$1*");
System.out.println(inputString);
```

Prints

```
This is a User, *[USER 1]*, and a second user *[USER 2]*
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as simple as this:

```
String s = inputString.replaceAll("\\[.*?]", "*$0*")
```

No capture groups needed.

*Result*

```
This is a User, *[USER 1]*, and a second user *[USER 2]*
```

*Explanation*

```
\\[     Match '[', escaped since '[' has special meaning, double-escaped because of Java
.*?     Match any text on single line, match as little as possible
]       Match ']', no need to escape since it's not in a character class
```

```
*       Literal '*'
$0      Entire matched text '[XXX]'
*       Literal '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace all `[` with - `*[*` and do the same for `]` using the string method `.replace(oldChar, newChar)` in java.